# add a page to the browser history without actually opening the page

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there any way to add a page to the browser history without opening that page in a new window or a new tab? using javascript

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that... Seems rather exploitable.

Comment: If the page you're pushing is on the same domain/origin as the page in which you're calling the script you can try using [`window.history#pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method).

Answer (score 2):

From native Javascript no, but if you're building a Chrome extension you have the ability to add a new URL to `chrome.history` like so:

```
chrome.history.addUrl({ url: "https://mozilla.com" }, function() {
  window.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
});
```

Comment: This answer seems rather out of context.

Comment: I agree in term of a native solution, but it's somewhat relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate browser's history with history API "pushState": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API